# Composition of differentiable with weakly differentiable function

Tags: functional-analysis, derivatives, chain-rule, weak-derivatives

Let $\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}$ be open. If I define a weakly differentiable function $u$ as $L^1_{loc}(\Omega)$ function for which the typical partial integration formula holds for all test functions, I know that the following chain rule holds:

Let $f\in C^1$ with $f'$ bounded, then $f\circ u$ is again weakly differentiable with the usual derivative $f'(u)u'(x)$.

I can prove this via a density argument. However, I see no way to prove this without the boundedness of $f'$. Does this result hold without the condition or if not, can anybody state an easy "counter example" for where the weak differentiability of the composition with an arbitray $C^1$-map can go wrong?

Comment: The boundedness of $f'$ is used to show that $f'(u)u'$ is integrable, and it can be relaxed certainly if we more about $u$.

Comment: Okay, I agree that if we would know more about $u$ (I guess that is what you wanted to write) we could relax the condition on $f$. But let's assume we know nothing more about $u$ than the fact that it is weakly differentiable. Is there an example of choosing $u$ and $f\in C^1$ s.t. $f\circ u$ is not weakly differentiable?

Answer (score 3):

As the other answer pointed out, the result is true for dimension 1. For an easy counterexample in $d=2$, let $\Omega=B_1(0)$ in dimension $2$, and consider the function
$$
u(x)=\begin{cases}
|x|^{-\alpha} & x\neq 0\\
0 & x=0
\end{cases}
$$
Convince yourself that this is weakly differentiable iff $\alpha <1$. Then simply take $f(x)=x^2$. Certainly this is $C^1$, but
$$
f(u)=\begin{cases}
|x|^{-2\alpha} & x\neq 0\\
0 & x=0
\end{cases}
$$
which is weakly differentiable iff $2\alpha <1$. So just take any $\alpha \in [\frac{1}{2},1)$ to get a counterexample.

Answer (score 2):

Weak differentiability is true without assumptions on $f'$. Take $\Omega\subset \mathbb R$, $u\in L^1_{loc}(\Omega)$ with weak derivative $u'\in L^1_{loc}(\Omega)$. Let $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ be continuously differentiable.

Take $\phi \in C^\infty_c(\Omega)$. Then $supp(\phi) \subset [a,b] \subset \Omega$ is a compact set, the restriction of $u$ to $[a,b]$  is in $W^{1,1}(a,b)$, hence $u$ is continuous on $[a,b]$. Hence, $|u|\le M$ on $[a,b]$ for some $M>0$. And in the integral $\int_\Omega f(u(x)) \phi(x)dx$ only the values of $f$ on $[-M,M]$ matter, $f'$ is bounded there, so $f(u)$ is weakly differentiable.

To see this, define $f_M(s):=f(s)$ for all $|s|\le M$, $f_M(s):= f(M) + f'(M)(s-M)$ for $s>M$, and similarly for $s<-M$. Then $f_M$ is continuously differentiable, with bounded derivative, and $f_M(u(x)) = f(u(x))$ for all $x\in [a,b]$. Then we can perform the integration by parts.

And $f(u)$ is weakly differentiable with $f'(u)u'\in L^1_{loc}(\Omega)$.

Comment: Thanks. If I understand you correctly, your main argument is that  for the conditions of the weak differentiability, we can restrict ourselves to a compact set. On this compact set, we conclude that $u$ is bounded. As $u$ is bounded, we can consider $f$ only on a bounded interval, where it's derivative will be bounded and therefore we can apply the known result. I agree with this argument. Now suppose $\Omega$ would not be a subset of $\mathbb{R}$, but of $\mathbb{R}^d$ for a $d>1$. Can I still conclude in this case that $u$ is bounded (as I do not have the continuity anymore)?

Comment: I suspect that this only works for $d=1$. For $d>1$ there are unbounded weakly differentiable functions...